# How to break a command execution in Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-idle, pyserial

I was using PySerial when I typed

```
serialObject.read()
```

And the execution hanged waiting for some serial data.
How to abort this command? I want to type new commands and ignore this one.
I'm using IDLE on Windows and Ctrl+C doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ctrl-C should work, you'll get a `KeyboardInterrupt`.  Either something at a lower level is hanging the process or PySerial might be trapping the exception I suppose

Comment: If this is dispatching out to C code via the Python/C API, it's common for signal handling to get dropped in the process. I don't know anything about sending signals to processes in Windows, or I could offer more advice. ;)

Comment: I could avoid this altogether by using `serialObject.timeout = 1` so it won't hang indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure PySerial to timeout if no data is received before the time limit.  If you don't have a timeout, then your only option is to ask the OS to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried spamming CTRL-C?
Not sure why, but sometimes I have to repeatedly press CTRL+C to get the darn prgram to quit.

You could also try hijacking CTRL-C with something like this:

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

but I'm not sure that will really help if the normal CTRL+C isn't working.

Comment: pyserial apparently has problems with keyboard interupts -____-.
It seems that x03 is interpreted as CTRL+C
but I'm not sure why that is/if it works. Worth a try though.
http://pastebin.com/bGQLc1wk